# Chart in PowerPoint not always updated when the data in the embedded Excel file is updated

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I have the following VBA code in PowerPoint which opens the embedded Excel file behind the chart

```
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim myChart As PowerPoint.Chart

Dim Wb As Object
Dim App As Object

Set myPresentation = ActivePresentation
Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides("S2").Shapes("CA1")
    
    Set myChart = shp.Chart
    myChart.ChartData.Activate
    myChart.Refresh
    Set Wb = myChart.ChartData.Workbook
    Set App = Wb.Application
```

I have then the following VBA code in Excel which paste in new data in the just opened embedded Excel file

```
LR_CA1 = Sheet02.Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks("Chart in Microsoft PowerPoint").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D" & LR_CA1 - 
5).Value = Sheet02.Range("Y7:AB" & LR_CA1).Value

Workbooks("Chart in Microsoft PowerPoint").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

As such everything works well. However sometimes when I after I have run the code goes and look at the chart in PowerPoint the new data is not displayed in the chart. If I then manually opens the embedded Excel file I can see that the embedded Excel file do hold the updated data. This is often the case if the code add additional data to the chart. For example if the chart before had data for 2019-2022 and then after running the code the chart should hold data for 2019-2023. The embedded Excel file is then updated with data for 2019-2023 but the chart still only show 2019-2022.

When I manually re-open the embedded Excel file the table is extended so it covers the newly pasted-in data. And when I then manually alter the Table range, then the data finally becomes visible in the chart

[Embedded excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vLwb.png)

I have tried to add a code which would alter the table range as well, but running it doesn't seem to help

```
Workbooks("Chart in Microsoft PowerPoint").Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Resize 
Range("A1:D" & LR_CA1 - 6)
Workbooks("Chart in Microsoft PowerPoint").Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Resize 
Range("A1:D" & LR_CA1 - 5)
```

So my question is. Why is not the chart displaying the correct data, even if the correct data is shown in the embedded Excel file? And does anyone know of a solution to my problem? To paste in the charts from Excel into PowerPoint is unfortunately not an option.

Finally if I right click on the chart and instead of choosing "Edit Data in Excel" choose just "Edit data" then the newly data pasted in doesn't seem to be part of the displayed data here. Even if the table is expanded

[Embedded Excel file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxlkC.png)